# Uninstalling one Installer from another installer - error 1618

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have created a custom installer dll & everything is working fine.  I just want to call another installer's `Uninstall` method from my current installation.  When I do this, I get `error code 1618` (signifies another installer is already running).  However when I call the `uninstall` of the same product from a test project, it is working fine.

Could anyone suggest a solution to this?

Can I uninstall another application from the current installer?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK calling an installer (either to install or uninstall) from another installer is not supported. It was supported in earlier versions of Windows Installer, but is now deprecated, and even then I'm not sure uninstallation of an other product was supported.
The recommended way now is to use a bootstrapper to check for and install any prerequisites. Theoretically you should also be able to uninstall a product using a custom bootsrapper, however writing one is not a trivial exercise.
Also silently uninstalling something from a users machine is not necessarily a nice thin. Using the Visual Studio 2005 Generic Bootstrapper you should be able to generate a bootstrapper that checks if the other product is installed and asks the user to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

If this other product is your own (and hence you have access to what the installer should be doing), or you want to do something dirty, you could try removing the files/registry entries/etc yourself then unregistering the program in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL(MACHINE|USER)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{PROGRAM}`). Not really the greatest idea ever, but if you have access to what the installer should be doing, then it'll work for you.